# Google Sheets: how to down-fill and prevent incrementing in a specific Cell Number Reference

Tags: arrays, regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

Formula:

```
=IFNA(INDEX(TRIM(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(REGEXEXTRACT($A3, B1&"(.+)"), "]"), "[", ), 1, 2))), 0)
```

I want to down-fill and prevent incrementing in `B1` Cell Number Reference, I mean I want to change the Number Reference of `A3` cell, example: A3 - A4 - A5 - A6 ... but I don' want to change the Number Reference of `B1` cell when down-filling.

I hope my question is understandable.

Comment: make absolute by `$B$1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use arrayformula:

```
=IFNA(INDEX(IF($A3:$A="",,TRIM(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(
 REGEXEXTRACT($A3:$A, B1&"(.+)"), "]"), "[", ), 99^99, 2)))), 0)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @player0, I have a problem when I got the data entry, all formulas in the row removed once the customer enters his data and recorded in the spreadsheet, how I can disable or avoid formula removing when the data come?

Comment: This seems like another question really, but if some user is putting data where the formula is there is no chance to recover the formula. You could protect the range or create an script to solve the issue. If you still have doubts go ahead and create another new question to get a solution there.

Comment: Hi bro, I have post new question as you suggested, here is my new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62044869/google-sheets-the-formula-deleted-by-google-form-entries-answers , if you can help me with this issue too I will be thankful to you! regards

Comment: @James you can use this in F2: `={"Quantity","Price EUR";IFNA(INDEX(IF($A3:$A="",,TRIM(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(
 REGEXEXTRACT($A3:$A, B1&"(.+)"), "]"), "[", ), 99^99, 2)))), 0)}`

Comment: Hi @player0, thank you this issue was fixed by the same formula you give me now. I have another issue now is how to SUM the Price even if some Cells are empty because they don't receive any data?

Comment: I have tried with this formula `=SUMIFS($G$2:$G,$F$2:$F,"<>",$G$2:$G,"<"&99^99)` but it doesn't count and only give me `0` in result