# The formula deleted by Google Form entries (answers)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

The Formula gets deleted once I get new answers submitted by customers!

Here is the test store: https://test-stoore21.myshopify.com/products/1st-product-title , add this product to cart and enter any random data to **Shipping information** form and click confirm, then check this Sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xoNPfIfrVv7jF8W3Pa67Iu9oJRz2NOncW7oLQ94mWQ4

As you can see the Formula in the CELL of **`F`** Column gets deleted once data comes in.

Any script or trick to avoid deleting the Formula when the data comes in?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your formula to:

```
=IFNA(INDEX(TRIM(ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(REGEXEXTRACT($E2:$E, $F$1&"(.+)"), "]"), "[", )))), 0)
```

Place it in cell `F2` and delete everything under it.

It is the `ARRAY_CONSTRAIN` that gives you troubles.

Comment: AMAZING! it's working well now and the formula is applied on all cells even if new data comes in, it's doesn't remove like before! Thank you so much @marikamitsos

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: Little by little we'll make your shop working as it should :)

Comment: It will be working as it should with your help <3 , I really appreciate all your efforts

Comment: Dear @marikamitsos, the formula working great as I said, but there's an issue, when I put the formula in **`F2`** it should get Quantity in **`F2`** cell and the Price in  **`G2`** cell then stop getting any other next value, but it gives me `#REF!` error I tried this formula: `=IFNA(INDEX(TRIM(ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(REGEXEXTRACT($E2:$E, $F$1&"(.+)"), "]"), "[", ), 1, 2))), 0)` but I get 0

Comment: You get `#REF!` because cells that should be reserved empty for the formula to expand , are not. As for the second formula, to make it work, you need to change it to `=IFNA(INDEX(TRIM(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(REGEXEXTRACT($E2:$E, $F$1&"(.+)"), "]"), "[", ), 99^99, 2))), 0)`

Comment: Now it's working well, the last question about this formula, how to write $0.00 when the customer doesn't buy a product, for example, the **3rd Product title** ( https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKBB5.png ) and I'm sorry for asking you more questions, thank you!

Comment: In this case, use this `=IFNA(INDEX(TRIM(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(REGEXEXTRACT($E2:$E, $F$1&"(.+)"), "]"), "[", ), 99^99, 2))*1), 0)`. Notice the `*1`? This makes all the difference. It also fixes your product values which were returned as text instead of numbers. All is left for you is to now format the money columns from the menu as `Currency`